# Integrating a rational function.

Tags: integration

How to integrate $$\int_1^{\infty}\frac{2x^3-1}{x^6+2x^3+\sqrt3x^2+1}{\rm d}x$$
The bottom is not factorizable hence no partial fractions. There seems no other way.

Comment: A non-factorizable 6th-degree polynomial?  I don't think so.

Comment: @GEdgar ಠ_ಠ ${}$

Answer (score 16, accepted):

$$\begin{align}\int_{1}^{\infty}\frac{2x^3-1}{x^6+2x^3+\sqrt 3x^2+1}dx&=\int_{1}^{\infty}\frac{2x^3-1}{(x^3+1)^2+\sqrt 3x^2}dx\\&=\int_{1}^{\infty}\frac{(2x^3-1)/(x^2)}{\left((x^3+1)^2+\sqrt 3x^2\right)/(x^2)}dx\\&=\int_{1}^{\infty}\frac{2x-\frac{1}{x^2}}{\left(x^2+\frac 1x\right)^2+\sqrt 3}dx\\&=\int_{2}^{\infty}\frac{du}{u^2+\sqrt 3}\ \ \ \ (\text{set $x^2+\frac 1x=u$})\\&=\int_{\arctan\frac{2}{\sqrt[4]{3}}}^{\frac{\pi}{2}}\frac{d\theta}{\sqrt[4]{3}}\ \ \ \ (\text{set $u=\sqrt[4]{3}\tan\theta$})\\&=\frac{1}{2\sqrt[4]{3}}\left(\pi-2\arctan\frac{2}{\sqrt[4]{3}}\right).\end{align}$$

Comment: Very well done (+1)!

Comment: how'd you get that idea?

Comment: @ADG: All I noticed was $x^6+2x^3+1=(x^3+1)^2$. After that, only one way, isn't it?

Comment: ok would you complete?

Comment: @ADG: You'll get $\int_{2}^{\infty}\frac{du}{u^2+\sqrt 3}$. I'm sure you can continue.

Comment: yes I can but i just asked if you would comlete here for the sake of completenes, anyways you say, arctan u/sqrtsqrt3.

Comment: @ADG: I did that:)